# Normalize text with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, similarity

I need a function to normalize data.
For example: in column A there are the reference data (written correctly) and in column B the data to correct.

Is there a function that can find the most similar data (maybe based on consecutive characters in common) and substitute the wrong written data with the right one, as the following example?

[image]

Thanks

Tried some formulas but did'nt work

Comment: This is likely to need VBA rather than just formulae. Your best bet is to hire a freelance coder and expect to have to iterate a few times. It also depends on how big the data sets are: searching the whole of column A for the best match might be too slow if you have thousands of names.

Comment: Have you tried the following Add-ins, I haven't used but it seems to fit your purpose, maybe there are other similar Add-ins, I did a search by: excel fuzzy lookup. This is one of the page I found: https://www.statology.org/fuzzy-matching-in-excel/

Comment: This is another good source, it seems this fuzzy logic for O365 is out of the box under Power Query: https://sfmagazine.com/articles/2021/january/excel-fuzzy-matching/

Answer (score 0):

If data does not get more complicated than that, try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A:A,3),MAP(TOCOL(B:B,3)&" ",LAMBDA(a,XLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("*",0,"",TEXTSPLIT(a,TEXTSPLIT(a,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),,1),,1),""),VSTACK(x,SUBSTITUTE(x," ",)),VSTACK(x,x),,2))))
```

Idea here is:

- Variable `x` - Return an array of values in column A;
- Use `MAP()` to loop all values in column B;

  - First `TEXTSPLIT()` the value on all uppercase chars to then split the input based on the remainder;
  - `TEXTJOIN()` the returned array with an asterisk to allow for wildcard matching;
  - Use `XLOOKUP()` for a wildcard match in an array where 'x' is vstacked with it's space-removed counterpart.

This should now return the 1st match that has the same sequence of characters.

I do agree with the comment-section that for a better match on similarity, you may want to look at other options. One option that I could think of while still using formulae is:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A:A,3),MAP(TOCOL(B:B,3)&" ",LAMBDA(a,LET(z,FILTER(VSTACK(x,x),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTJOIN("*",0,"",TEXTSPLIT(a,TEXTSPLIT(a,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),,1),,1),""),VSTACK(x,SUBSTITUTE(x," ",))))),@SORTBY(z,LEN(z))))))
```

Way more verbose, but here you'd `FILTER()` all values that could be a wildcard match using the same logic as the other formula. Though here, the outcome is filtered by length, making it a little bit more likely to return the value that shared the best similarity.